# Public fermentation/cell cultivation database?

Tags: cell-culture, database, biotechnology, data, fermentation

I am wondering if there are any large collections of fermentation or cell cultivation data publicly available.
I am interested in all cell types used within industrial biotech and biopharma, especially the most common ones, e.g. CHO, yeast, e.coli, bacillus, lactis.

I am interested in this from a process understanding point of view. So I am very interested in the conditions throughout (pH, nutrients, dissolved oxygen, media comp, turbidity, etc.) as a time series. If manual (offline) measurements are made, CFU, amount of metabolite produced, etc. they would also be incredibly interesting to have.

I have looked around without luck.
I guess the 'perfect' database probably doesn't exist, but I haven't been able to find anything.
So I would really appreciate help finding any dataset on fermentation data, even if it doesn't have all that I am looking for.

---

I found this article: [Bio-Ferment A Database on Bioreactor and Fermentation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235394286_Bio-Ferment_A_Database_on_Bioreactor_and_Fermentation) from 2011, but I cannot find the actual database.

Comment: What kind of data are you seeking? Growth conditions? OD? Something metabolic?

Comment: What kinds of cells? Yeast, human, bacterial? What do "online" and "offline" mean? What kinds of fermentation? What is the readout- metabolite production, cell density, biomass?

Comment: @tyersome I am especially looking for growth conditions and OD. I have re-phrased the question so that it is hopefully more informative.

Comment: @MaximilianPress online means that the measurements are made continually - e.g. a probe sitting in the tank. Offline is when someone manually takes a sample and makes the measurement outside the tank.